# Cocos2dx Assets getting replaced by Default HelloWorld Package

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

So i have started coding in Cocos2dx but in my first app only the assets are getting replaced by the deafult HelloWorld Assets.

i have only modified the init method in HelloWorld.cpp file.

Anyone knows is this a bug ?

NOTE : i am using andorid-ndk-r8b,cocos2dx-2.0.1 on windows 7 64-bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your assets in the Resource folder using Windows Explorer..and then build your app again ..Hope this helps !!